# Alternative way to represent to open or close a dropdown?

Tags: gui-design, user-behavior, user-expectation, icons, dropdown

I'm doing some animation icons for a recent product and I'm playing with some alternative to the standard dropdown toggle. Typically, it's a arrow pointing either down or up...

Is there any reason to not have it a chevron down and then an X icon to close? Would this impact any user expectations or the web standards / what people are used to?

Here's an example of what I'm suggesting: https://codepen.io/brycesnyder/pen/XWWbZEz

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend the 'x' icon, because it breaks with conventions. An 'x' typically closes a window or container (e.g. makes it vanish), so user might get the impression that the whole dropdown would be removed when clicking on that 'x'.

However, up and downward pointing chevrons are associated with expanding/collapsing content in the given direction, which is exactly what is happening with dropdowns.